# NoteID field in CSAnswers table

Tags: sql, acumatica

Starting in 2018 R2, there's a new NoteID field in the CSAnswers (attribute value) tables. Interestingly, the CSAnswers DAC has no reference to this field, yet the values get populated with a new unique identifier just fine. I searched in the Note table and don't see any reference to these note IDs, so it looks like they were generated when the data was inserted.

Since there's no default value at the SQL level either, I'm wondering where this is being set - can anyone explain the mechanism that causes this field to be initialized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CSAnswers` DAC has `CSAnswersExt : PXCacheExtension<CSAnswers>` in `PX.Objects.GDPR` namespace. This extension has `PseudonymizationStatus` and `NoteID` fields.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to search for cache extensions. Makes sense now :)